# What exactly is the Linux documentation resources available within the operating system?

Tags: linux

I am reviewing the job description for a position as a CO OP intern with Intel, and I came across this line:

> 3 months of experience in Linux system by using the documentation resources available within the operating system (without using Google as a crutch).

I then Google'd about it and came across several websites. Which one should I look into to start building a stronger understanding of the Linux operating system?

Is this a good link: http://www.tldp.org/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manuals are your friend on GNU/Linux - Manuals are called `man` and the command to find information on GNU/Linux is also `man`. Take a look at http://www.linfo.org/man.html.

TLDP - The Linux Documentation Project is definitely a good resource. However, the line you mention indicates that they would like you to find answers to your own questions using `man`. For example, if you wanted to know what different options exists for `ls`, you could type on command line `man ls`.

You could also use the command `info`. Check out some search results related to the difference between `man` and `info` here: https://www.google.com/search?q=man+vs.+info

Both `man` and `info` will help you with understanding GNU/Linux better. I'd recommend relying also on books, TLDP and youtube/pluralsight videos.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to build a great knowledge about Linux, you need try one of distros available: Ubuntu, Mint, Debian, Mageia... (There are many distros you can choose).
After using one Linux distribution you chose, start diving in command lines. You can get some help in community, google...

Linux has a command called "man" that is a manual (documentation) for commands.
Example: the command "cp" copy files and directories, when you type "man cp", you have a documentation for command cp. I think man is the command for documentation you mentioned.